# preventing absolute button from overlapping inputs

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

the form itself will expand as the page is shrunk. I have a button that uses position:absolute;bottom:0; to keep it at the bottom of the page. When the page is shrunk the button overlaps the inputs.
I created a 3rd div to butt up with the button and use margin-bottom:10px; so the 2 should never touch div3 and button_holder. but it still overlaps. How can i prevent the 2 divs from overlapping each other? Even tho the button is absolute the div3 should still expand the form by pushing the whole form down when using display:table;

```css
#service_wrap {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    max-height: 400px;
    display: table;
    background-color: #000;
    background-image: url('../images/thumbsup.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
h1 {
    color: #FFF;
    width: 90%;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 4%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
    padding-left: 3%;
}
h2 {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 17px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
}
h3 {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 1%;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
}
h4 {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 3%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
}
h5 {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 3%;
    margin-bottom: 8%;
}
h6 {
    color: #FFF;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 100px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 10%;
}
#thingstoknow {
    border: 2px solid red;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 46px;
    height: 48px;
    display: table;
}
#thingstoknow a {
    color: #FFF;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {} #service_top {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:60%;
    display:table;
    margin-bottom:8%;
}
#service_bottom {
    height: 49%;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    margin-bottom: 8%;
}
/*     estimate form     */
/*form styles*/

#AUTO {
    display: table;
    /*makes div fill content*/
    
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    border: px solid green;
    /*visual aid to make sure div fills content*/
    
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
#AUTO fieldset {
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 350px;
    position: relative;
    width: 95%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #FFF;
    display: table;
    /*makes div fill content*/
}
#miles {
    display: none;
    /*spammer fills this out and it gets rejected my mail script*/
}
/*Hide all except first fieldset*/

#AUTO fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
    display: none;
    /*remove to see all feildsets*/
}
#AUTO fieldset {
    display: none
}
#AUTO fieldset:first-child {
    display: block;
}
#AUTO .div1 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 240px;
    height: 65px;
    left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: px solid blue;
    /*visual aid to make sure div fills content*/
}
#AUTO .div2 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}
#AUTO .div3 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#contact_name {
    text-align: left;
    margin: 10px;
    min-width: 170px;
    width: 25%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    /*visual aid to make sure div fills content*/
}
#contact_phone {
    text-align: left;
    margin: 10px;
    min-width: 170px;
    width: 25%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#contact_email {
    text-align: left;
    margin: 10px;
    min-width: 170px;
    width: 25%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.button_holder {
    width: 98%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
input,
select,
textarea {
    -ms-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
}
#contact_slide1 {
    display: table;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
#contact_slide2 {
    display: table;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
#contact_contact {
    min-width: 170px;
    width: 30%;
    display: table;
    float: right;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#contact_message {
    width: 70%;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#contact_slide3 {
    display: table;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
input {
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 95%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 46px;
    height: 30px;
}
textarea {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    clear: both;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
select {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    float: left;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 35px;
    height: 35px;
}
input[type=submit] {
    border: 2px solid #F00;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 30%;
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    line-height: 46px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #F00;
    color: #FFF;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
input[type=button] {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 30%;
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    line-height: 46px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #FFF;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
/*     ADDITIONAL SERVICES     */

#additional_services {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 350px;
    font-size: 14px;
    display: table;
    background-color: #CCC;
}
/*     map and locations     */

#loc_holder {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 350px;
    display: table;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
#loc_buttons {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #0F0;
    display: none;
}
#loc_info {
    border: px solid red;
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 47%;
    height: 420px;
    float: left;
    overflow: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 1%;
}
#loc_map {
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 47%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    height: 400px;
    display: table;
}
#mloc {
    width: 96.9%;
    border: px solid blue;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 3%;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #CCC;
}
#mloc_left {
    width: 55%;
    height: 115px;
    display: table;
    border: px solid green;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 3%;
}
#loc_info_dir {
    padding: 2%;
    width: 30%;
    height: 110px;
    display: table;
    float: left;
}
#loc_info_dir #loc_info_maplink {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 3%;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 13px;
}
#loc_info_dir #loc_info_maplink a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#loc_info_dir #loc_info_dist {
    border: 1px solid purple;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
    /* delete when sql code is done*/
}
.maptitle {
    width: 99%;
    border: px solid red;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.manager {
    width: 99%;
    border: px solid red;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    margin-top: 3px;
}
.manager span {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.addy1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 99%;
    border: px solid red;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.addy2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 99%;
    border: px solid red;
}
.phone1 {
    width: 99%;
    border: px solid red;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.fax1 {
    width: 99%;
    border: px solid red;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<form id="AUTO"   method="post" action="">
   <!-- fieldsets -->
   <fieldset>
      <div class="div3">
         <div class="div1"><img src="images/step1.png" width="233" height="65"></div>
         <h3>CONTACT INFO</h3>
         <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>"/>
         <input type="hidden" name="miles" value=""/>
         <div id="contact_name">FULL NAME: *<br>
            <input id="element_2_1" name="name" class="element text" size="15" maxlength="15" value="" type="text" placeholder="FULL NAME">
         </div>
         <div id="contact_phone">PHONE NUMBER: *<br>
            <input id="element_1" name="phone" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" placeholder="PHONE NUMBER"/>
         </div>
         <div id="contact_email">EMAIL:<br>
            <input id="element_1" name="email" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" placeholder="EMAIL ADDRESS"/>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!--div3-->
      <div class="button_holder">
         <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next"/>
      </div>
   </fieldset>
   <fieldset>
      <div class="div3">
         <div class="div1"><img src="images/step2.png" width="233" height="65"></div>
         <h3>VEHICLE INFO</h3>
         <div id="contact_name">VEHICLE MAKE: *<br>
            <input id="element_2_1" name="make" class="element text" size="15" maxlength="15" value="" type="text" placeholder="FULL NAME">
         </div>
         <div id="contact_phone">VEHICLE MODEL: *<br>
            <input id="element_1" name="model" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" placeholder="PHONE NUMBER"/>
         </div>
         <div id="contact_email">YEAR*:<br>
            <input id="element_1" name="year" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" placeholder="EMAIL ADDRESS"/>
         </div>
         <div id="contact_name">VIN NUMBER: <br>
            <input id="element_2_1" name="vin" class="element text" size="15" maxlength="15" value="" type="text" placeholder="FULL NAME">
         </div>
         <div id="contact_phone">INSURANCE COMPANY ( if applicable ):<br>
            <input id="element_1" name="insurance_company" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" placeholder="PHONE NUMBER"/>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!--div3-->
      <div class="button_holder">
         <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next"/>
         <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous"/>
      </div>
   </fieldset>
   <fieldset>
      <div class="div3">
         <div class="div1"><img src="images/step3.png" width="233" height="65"></div>
         <div id="contact_message">MESSAGE:<br>
            <textarea id="element_3" name="message" class="element textarea medium" placeholder="START TYPING MESAGE HERE..."></textarea>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!--div3-->
      <div class="button_holder">
         <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="ALMOST DONE"/>
         <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
      </div>
   </fieldset>
   <fieldset>
      <div class="div3">
         <div class="div1"><img src="images/step4.png" width="233" height="65"></div>
         <h4>THANK YOU!</h4>
         <h5>Once you hit Submit a representative will be with you shortly. </h5>
      </div>
      <!--div3-->
      <div class="button_holder">
         <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="SUBMIT" />
         <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous"  />
      </div>
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```css
#service_wrap{
padding:0;
margin:0;
width:100%;
height:400px;
max-height:400px;
display:table;
background-color:#000;
background-image: url('../images/thumbsup.jpg') ;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
} 
h1{
color:#FFF;
width:90%;
text-align:center;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:22px;
text-transform:uppercase;
margin-top:4%;
margin-bottom:3%;
padding-left:3%;
}
h2{color:#FFF;
font-size:17px;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top:5%;
margin-bottom:5%;
}
h3{
color:#000;
font-size:15px;
width:100%;
text-decoration:underline;
text-align:center;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top:1%;
margin-bottom:1%;
}
h4{
color:#000;
font-size:15px;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top:3%;
margin-bottom:3%;
}
h5{
color:#000;
font-size:12px;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top:3%;
margin-bottom:8%;
}
h6{
color:#FFF;
width:100%;
margin-top:100px;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:16px;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align:center;
text-transform:uppercase;
margin-top:10%;
}
#thingstoknow{
border: 2px solid red;
border-radius: 3px;
width:30%;
margin: 0 auto;
text-transform:uppercase;
font-size:15px;
text-align:center;
line-height:46px;
height:48px;
display:table;
} 

#thingstoknow a{color:#FFF;width:100%;height:100%;display:block;text-decoration:none;
white-space:nowrap;
text-align:center;
padding-right:20px;}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {}
#service_top{
margin: 0 auto;
width:60%;
display:table;
margin-bottom:8%;
}
#service_bottom{
height:49%;
width:100%;
display:table;
margin-bottom:8%;
}
/*     estimate form     */


/*form styles*/
#AUTO {
display:table;/*makes div fill content*/
width: 100%;
margin:0 auto;
position: relative;
border:px solid green; /*visual aid to make sure div fills content*/
margin-bottom:30px;
}
#AUTO fieldset {
text-align:center;
min-height:350px;
position:relative;
width:95%;
margin:0 auto;
background-color:#FFF;
display:table;/*makes div fill content*/
}
#miles{
display:none;/*spammer fills this out and it gets rejected my mail script*/
}
/*Hide all except first fieldset*/
#AUTO fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
display: none;/*remove to see all feildsets*/
}
#AUTO fieldset {
display:none
}
#AUTO fieldset:first-child {
display: block;
}
#AUTO .div1{
margin:0 auto;
width: 240px;
height:65px;
left:10px;
margin-top:10px;
margin-bottom:20px;
border:px solid blue; /*visual aid to make sure div fills content*/
}
#AUTO .div2{
margin:0 auto;
width: 100%;
display:table;
}
#AUTO .div3{
margin:0 auto;
width: 100%;
display:table;
border: 1px solid red;
margin-bottom:10px;
}

#contact_name{
text-align:left;
margin:10px;
min-width:170px;
width:25%;
display:inline-block;
vertical-align: middle; /*visual aid to make sure div fills content*/
}
#contact_phone{text-align:left;margin:10px;min-width:170px;width:25%;display:inline-block; vertical-align: middle;white-space:nowrap;
}
#contact_email{text-align:left;margin:10px;min-width:170px;width:25%;display:inline-block; vertical-align: middle;
}
.button_holder {
width: 98%;
margin:0 auto;
display:table;
margin-top:30px;
margin-bottom:10px;
position: relative;
bottom:0px;
}







input, select, textarea{

    
    -ms-box-sizing:content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:content-box;
    box-sizing:content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:content-box; 
}
#contact_slide1{display:table;width:70%;margin: 0 auto;
margin-bottom:30px;
margin-top:30px;}
#contact_slide2{display:table;width:70%;margin: 0 auto;margin-bottom:30px;
margin-top:30px;}

#contact_contact{min-width:170px;width:30%;display:table;float:right;
white-space:nowrap;}



#contact_message{width:70%;display:table;margin: 0 auto;margin-bottom:20px;}

#contact_slide3{display:table;width:70%;margin: 0 auto;margin-bottom:30px;
margin-top:30px;}

input {


border: 2px solid black;
border-radius: 4px;
width:95%;
text-align:center;
line-height:46px;
height:30px;
}
textarea {margin: 0 auto;
text-align:center;
clear:both;
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius: 1px;
width:100%;margin: 0 auto;
text-align:center;
display: block;

margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
text-align:center;
height:100px;margin: 0 auto;
text-align:center;
}
select {  text-transform:uppercase;

 float:left;
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius: 1px;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
line-height:35px;
height:35px;
}
input[type=submit] { 
border: 2px solid #F00;
border-radius: 5px;
width:30%;
text-align:center;
float:right;
line-height:46px;
height:50px;
background-color:#F00;
color:#FFF;
margin-left:5px;margin-right:5px;
}
input[type=button] {
text-transform:uppercase;
border: 2px solid #000;
border-radius: 5px;
width:30%;
text-align:center;
float:right;
line-height:46px;
height:50px;
background-color:#000;
color:#FFF;
margin-left:5px;margin-right:5px;
}
/*     ADDITIONAL SERVICES     */
#additional_services{
width:100%;
margin: 0 auto;
height:350px;
font-size:14px;
display:table;
background-color:#CCC;
}
/*     map and locations     */
#loc_holder{
background-color:#f0f0f0;
width:100%;
height:350px;
display:table;
padding-bottom:20px;
padding-top:20px;
}
#loc_buttons{
width:100%;
height:100px;
background-color:#0F0;
display:none;
}
#loc_info{border:px solid red;
background-color:#FFF;
width:47%;
height:420px;
float:left;
overflow:scroll;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
margin-left:2%;
margin-right:1%;
}
#loc_map{
background-color:#FFF;
width:47%;float:left;
margin-left:1%;
margin-right:2%;
height:400px;
display:table;
}
#mloc{
width:96.9%;
border:px solid blue;
float:left;
margin: 0 auto;
padding-left:3%;
padding-bottom:2%;
margin-bottom:2%;
border-bottom: 2px solid #CCC;
}
#mloc_left{
width:55%;
height:115px;
display:table;
border:px solid green;
float:left;
padding-left:3%;
}
#loc_info_dir{
padding:2%;
width:30%;
height:110px;
display:table;
float:left;
}
#loc_info_dir #loc_info_maplink{width:80%;margin:0 auto;
margin-top:3%;
margin-bottom:10%;
text-align:center;
font-size:13px;}
#loc_info_dir #loc_info_maplink a{
text-decoration:none;
}
#loc_info_dir #loc_info_dist{border:1px solid purple;width:80%;margin:0 auto;
margin-top:10%;
margin-bottom:3%;
text-align:center;
display:none;/* delete when sql code is done*/
}
.maptitle{ width:99%;
border:px solid red;
font-weight:bold;
text-transform:uppercase;}
.manager{width:99%;
border:px solid red;
margin-bottom:3px;margin-top:3px;}
.manager span{
font-weight:bold;
}
.addy1{text-transform:uppercase;width:99%;
border:px solid red;margin-bottom:3px;}
.addy2{text-transform:uppercase;width:99%;
border:px solid red;}
.phone1{width:99%;
border:px solid red;
font-size:12px;font-weight:600;}
.fax1{width:99%;
border:px solid red;font-size:12px;font-weight:600;}
```

```html
<form id="AUTO"   method="post" action="">

<!-- fieldsets -->
<fieldset>
<div class="div3">

<div class="div1"><img src="images/step1.png" width="233" height="65"></div>

<h3>CONTACT INFO</h3>
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="miles" value=""/>
<div id="contact_name">FULL NAME: *<br>
<input id="element_2_1" name="name" class="element text" size="15" maxlength="15" value="" type="text" placeholder="FULL NAME"></div>  
 

<div id="contact_phone">PHONE NUMBER: *<br>
<input id="element_1" name="phone" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" placeholder="PHONE NUMBER"/></div> 

<div id="contact_email">EMAIL:<br>
<input id="element_1" name="email" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" placeholder="EMAIL ADDRESS"/>
</div> 






</div><!--div3-->
<div class="button_holder">
<input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next"/>
</div>



</fieldset>





<fieldset>
<div class="div3">
<div class="div1"><img src="images/step2.png" width="233" height="65"></div>


<h3>VEHICLE INFO</h3>

<div id="contact_name">VEHICLE MAKE: *<br>
<input id="element_2_1" name="make" class="element text" size="15" maxlength="15" value="" type="text" placeholder="FULL NAME"></div>  
 

<div id="contact_phone">VEHICLE MODEL: *<br>
<input id="element_1" name="model" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" placeholder="PHONE NUMBER"/></div> 

<div id="contact_email">YEAR*:<br>
<input id="element_1" name="year" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" placeholder="EMAIL ADDRESS"/>
</div> 


<div id="contact_name">VIN NUMBER: <br>
<input id="element_2_1" name="vin" class="element text" size="15" maxlength="15" value="" type="text" placeholder="FULL NAME"></div>  
 

<div id="contact_phone">INSURANCE COMPANY ( if applicable ):<br>
<input id="element_1" name="insurance_company" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" placeholder="PHONE NUMBER"/></div> 





</div><!--div3-->
<div class="button_holder">
<input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next"/>
<input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous"/>
</div>


</fieldset> 

<fieldset>
<div class="div3">
<div class="div1"><img src="images/step3.png" width="233" height="65"></div>



<div id="contact_message">MESSAGE:<br>
<textarea id="element_3" name="message" class="element textarea medium" placeholder="START TYPING MESAGE HERE..."></textarea></div> 




</div><!--div3-->
<div class="button_holder">
<input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="ALMOST DONE"/>
<input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
</div>
</fieldset> 

<fieldset>
<div class="div3">
<div class="div1"><img src="images/step4.png" width="233" height="65"></div>

<h4>THANK YOU!</h4>
<h5>Once you hit Submit a representative will be with you shortly. </h5>
</div><!--div3-->
<div class="button_holder">
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="SUBMIT" />
<input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous"  />

</div>

</fieldset> 



</form>
```

Comment: that fixes the overlapping issue but by changing position:relative ; the button no longer stays at the bottom

Comment: why do you use field set here

Answer (score 0):

Hi not sure why you want the button at the bottom of the screen always, if it's a block element it will always be at the end of the form, but if 
you want to stop the overlap on mobile simply set your media query breakpoint and change its position to something like "static":

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .button_holder {
    position: static;
  } 
}
```

Comment: media queries is a last resort. Im looking for a more of a all around fix. I want the button at the bottom so as users are going through i don't want the buttons bouncing around the different forms as some have 2 fields some have 6

Comment: If you don't position the buttons absolute to start with, they will never overlap with the form fields.